# The space of sequence is infinite dimensional yet it seems Bolzano-Weiestrass applies

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

I got the following exercise :

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions defined on a countable set $A$ and such that :

$$\forall x \in A, \exists M_x > 0, \forall n, \mid f_n(x) \mid \leq M_x$$

Then prove that it’s possible to find an extraction $\phi$ such that forall $x$, $f_{\phi(n)}(x)$ converges for all $x$ in $A$.
It’s not difficult to construct such an extraction.

Moreover in a recent question I’ve  asked it says that Bolzano-Weiestrass is true only in finite dimensional vector spaces.

Yet, let’s say I take the space of sequence $u : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ then this is an infinite vector space.

But every sequence of this vector space : $a_n$ can be represented as follow :
$$a_1 = (f_1(x_1), f_1(x_2),...), a_2=(f_2(x_1), ...), a_n = (f_n(x_1),....,)$$

Hence every sequence can be represented as a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that $f_i : A \to \mathbb{R}$. Hence, by the property above this infinite vector space have the Bolzano-Weirstrass property since (thank’s to the exercises Îve cited above) we can find an extraction such that the sequence $a_{\phi(n)}$ converges.

So what’s the mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: I'm guessing "extraction" = subsequence...is this correct?

Comment: Yes your are right !

Comment: What is the notion of convergence i this space. You need a topology to talk about Bolzano -Weirstarss property.

Comment: @Ravi Rama Murthy, in this space a sequence converges if : $a_1 = (v_{1,1}, v_{1,2},...), a_n = (v_{n,1}, ...)$ converges iff $\forall i, \lim_{n \to \infty} v_{n,i} \in \mathbb{R}$, so that each component of the vector converges component wise

Comment: @Interestingproblems The statement that B-W holds only in finite dimensional spaces refers to normed linear spaces, not to the kind of space you are considering.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy just take Euclidean norm and this is equivalent to what I said

Comment: @Interestingproblems There is no such thing as Euclidean norm on the space of infinite bounded sequences.

Comment: @Ravi Rama Murthy, thank you, so actually there is no norm on the space of sequence such that a sequence of vector in this space  converge iff each of its component converge ?

Answer (score 0):

Your are working in a compact subset of an infinite-dimensional vectorspace. The (general) Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem says that every sequence in a compact metrizable space has a convergent subsequence.
You work in the product $\prod_{x\in A}[-M_x,M_x]$, which is compact and metrizable.

Comment: Thank you, si it means that B-W applies in this infinite vector space ?

Comment: The set you describe is not a vector space; it neither closed under addition nor under scalar multiplication.

Comment: The set of sequence is clearly closed under scalar multiplication and addition.

Comment: No, the function $f$ with values $f(x)=M_x$ is in the set but $2f$ is not.